# Message: JsonSyntaxException: duplicate key: AUDIT_HISTORY

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

public boolean isBookingForNonRegisteredEmpBySpocConfigEnabled(String buid) {

```
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
};
Optional<String> result = consul.keyValueClient().getValueAsString(String.format("%s%s%s",BASE_CONFIG_URL,buid,CONFIGURATION_CONSTANT));
Map<String, Object> config = result.<Map<String, Object>> map(s -> gson.fromJson(s, typeRef.getType())).orElse(null);
if(config != null) {
  logger.info("Getting config for {} : {}",BOOKING_FOR_NON_REG_EMP_BY_SPOC,
          config.get(BOOKING_FOR_NON_REG_EMP_BY_SPOC));
  return config.get(BOOKING_FOR_NON_REG_EMP_BY_SPOC) != null && (boolean) config.get(BOOKING_FOR_NON_REG_EMP_BY_SPOC);
}
return false;
```

}

this is throwing this exception,,,how to resolve?

Comment: Can you share the input string?

Comment: its a normal string

Comment: I mean it's content, it seems there is a duplicate key in your string content.

Comment: what to do to resolve this?